# Calculate real time distance traveled using google maps

Tags: java, android, list, google-maps, maps

There is a requirement to find the real time distance traveled using google maps. This should be calculated by the phone app itself. When I mean real time, I mean for example if the user is traveling to point A, the user can get to the point in many ways, what I want to do is calculate the total distance the user has traveled real time and not just assume and calculate the distance between the two points (which would not give the correct answer).

I googled around for this problem but could not find any method in doing so.

I personally thought of storing the longitude and latitude on the phone in a list and after the user reaches the destination the distance is caluclated using these points. However this means that I have to decide the interval in which these points are stored (every 1 min or so), which would mean that I would place location points in the list even though the user was actually still on the same road, which is quite unnecessary. Unless if anyone knows how to store the points at the appropriate time or some other solution

I am well more or less stumped on this problem, any help is really appreciated

The mobile platform is Android

Thanks,
MilindaD

Comment: When you say "real time distance", are you updating the Android with the distance in real time, or are you calculating the total distance just once at the end of a shift or day?

Comment: `real time distance` Do you mean the `real traveled way` or some sort of `he stood at x miles for 5 minutes before going on`?

Comment: What I meant was the real amount of km traveled, another way to put it is there is a driver who has an android phone, his dashboard says that he has traveled 0km at the start and after he reaches his destination it says 10km, the android phone should track the distance traveled and also say 10km at the end of the journey.

ALSO NOTE - There is no need to show the distance traveled till the journey then has been completed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best solution is to save the position each X seconds, and then calculate the total distance iterating between them, and to get the time, you just need to see the diference between the last point and the first one.

This is how gps tracking apps work.

Hope this helps ;)

Answer (score 1):

I did it once and it is fairly simple. Use a service with a LocationListener. On every onLocationChanged() save the current Location, At the end you can calculate with Location.distanceBetween() all distances between these saved Locations.

Please keep in mind that it becomes more accurate with faster tracking. For a walk you need less updates than driving a fast car. This can be set with minDistance and/or minTime in LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates().

Answer (score 0):

you could try takeing the start point (IIRC their Long and Lat) then the end point and working out the euclidean distance between the two (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance ).

I guess you what a better reloution then two point throgh, so take a third (or more) reading and work out A->B then add B->C.

Repeat for the resaloution you need.

to get the time of the journey. start a clock and stop it at the end (again you could take intermittent points if you wanted)